# Shower water temperature has changed in 2 of our upper level bathrooms...one is scalding hot & one is freezing cold!

Tags: plumbing, water, shower, heater, temperature

We have 3 upper level bathrooms where the shower temp has drastically changed in "2" of them. Our master bedroom shower all of a sudden only puts out only COLD water & my son's shower is scalding HOT? This happened to coincide immediately after we had a new refrigerator delivered from H. Depot and the service/delivery person shut our main water supply off while setting up the refrigerator? Our water heater is only 1 year old...how do we fix this! Could it have anything to do with them shutting the main water supply off while getting our fridge set up?

Comment: What kind of water heater is this--a gas fired tank or an electric powered tank or a gas fired tankless or something else?

Comment: A standard tank or a "tankless"? What size and do you have only one water heater? We have only one, but many houses in Dallas larger than our 2100 sq ft single story rancher have two. Is it possible you have more than one water heater? Go around the house and open all the hot water taps in showers, tubs, lavatories, kitchen, laundry room and let them all run for 1 to 2 min.  At the end of 1 to 2 min are they all hot? If not, which are cold? Then check your shower again.

Comment: In your bathroom with the shower running cold does the lavatory run hot?

Comment: It is a standard tank and we have "1"... Our house is 3,700 square feet. I'll check size and do what you suggested! Also, in our Master Bath, the (separate) bathtub and 2 sinks both get hot...it's just the shower that's cold.

Comment: I assume that you have one of those modern anti-scald valves on your shower, right? Most are single handle and prevent water that is too hot coming out of the shower.  It sounds to me that something went wrong with it when the water was turned off. Maybe it got jammed when the pressure dropped to zero and then suddenly came back on. The lavatories and (I think) the tub faucet do not have anti-scald valves.

Comment: It could be that the one in your shower got jammed in the cold position and your son's got jammed in the hot position. There is a calibration screw to reset them as the temperature of the cold water changes with the season.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback...sharing this with my husband when he gets home.

Comment: I am not an expert on this sort of problem. This is a DIY site and I am offering my thoughts in case you want to try to solve this yourself.  This *could* be the entire wrong track. Confirm that you have the modern shower valve with the anti scald feature. Do you have the instructions for the shower valves? Do both of these showers have  the same make and model of shower valve?

Comment: What kind of plumbing do you have? Is it copper tubing or PEX (plastic)? If it is PEX, does it have a manifold with cut-off valves? Could the hot water cut-off valve to your shower be closed and the cold water valve to your son's be closed?

Comment: Some shower valves have integral cut-off valves called "stop valves" which shut off the hot and the cold water to the valve. These are usually operated by turning with a flat-blade screwdriver. The purpose of this is to allow removal of the cartridge (the working part of the valve) without turning off the water to the house. If yours has these, turn them off and remove and inspect the cartridge. Prior to reinstalling the cartridge, open the stop valve on the hot supply and see if you get hot water. Obviously, if you do, then you know the fault is in the cartridge.

Comment: We have a shower system where there are supply faucets and then a tub faucet, a hand level shower head faucet and a head level faucet.  I can create the situation you describe by turning on the supply faucets (hot and cold) and leaving the individual show heads off.  The result is hot water out of the cold taps in the bathroom sink. Perhaps you have a set of faucets that is allowing this same type of pass through.

Comment: JonSG do you have a circulating hot water loop with the hot water pressurized above the cold water pressure? I didn't think to ask the OP if they have this arrangement, which they might have since they have only one hot water heater for a 3700 sq ft house.